# Unable to start Redis server in springboot maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, redis

I was not able to start the Redis server in the spring-boot maven project on mac. I checked the port, which was not occupied. For some unknown reason, I just couldn't start the Redis server.

I used the following as the maven dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This was the error message I got.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-08-14 00:45:59.933[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m808[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at edu.nyu.hw2280.SpringbootRedisApplication.main(SpringbootRedisApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1671) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1365) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1089) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:421) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:331) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1577) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:330) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.lambda$null$0(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:97) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:211) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:201) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:58) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:918) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:431) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:356) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:122) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:117) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.4.RELEASE.jar:6.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:103) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:715) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
```

And this was my redis configuration in the application.properties file.

```
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379  
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-wait=-1ms
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.timeout=3000ms
```

Thanks in advance for someone saving my life.

Comment: From the question I am not sure if you are running a redis server. It is a separated process from your Spring application, it is not embedded.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I initially thought that Redis is embedded just like tomcat.